# In jQuery, how can I address multiple selectors which are built from a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have a `change(function(){})` on a selector which is build from `text + 2` variables :

```
$('#rp_color_'+artnr+'_'+rpnr).change(function() {})
```

This is working fine, but I need to add `'#rp_volume_'+artnr+'_'+rpnr` as well but I am struggling with the quotes I think. I tried :

```
$('#rp_color_'+artnr+'_'+rpnr,'#rp_volume_'+artnr+'_'+rpnr).change(function() {}) 

$("'#rp_color_'+artnr+'_'+rpnr,'#rp_volume_'+artnr+'_'+rpnr").change(function() {}) 

$('"#rp_color_"+artnr+"_"+rpnr,"#rp_volume_"+artnr+"_"+rpnr').change(function() {})
```

But can't seem to find the right way. How would I be doing this?

Comment: `$('selector1, selector2')`?  Does this work for you?

Comment: `$('"#rp...` -- Also, that should be just `'` or `"`, not sure why you would use both?

Comment: Nope, that did not help because the problem was with the concatenation I did wrong, thx. As for your question about the quotes; you are referring to an example I gave of what I tried and did not work.

Comment: When I said `$('"#rp... -- Also, that should be just ' or "`, that's a concatenation issue, as I indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing seems to be due to confusion in keeping track of the concatenation of the various strings and variables; and the fact that the strings need to resolve to – in this case – a comma-separated string of selectors.

The simplest fix would be to simply address that confusion, keep track of the concatenation and keep the comma in the selector-string:

```
$('#rp_color_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr + ', #rp_volume_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr)
```

This, obviously, assumes that the variables `artnr` and `rpnr` contain valid CSS selector-strings.

It's worth introducing you to a slightly newer approach, using template-literal strings, delimited with the backtick (`) character, which allow you to use JavaScript variables within the string itself:

```
$(`#rp_color_${artnr}_${rnpr}, #rp_volume_${artnr}_${rpnr}`)
```

As a simplified demo:

```js
const artnr = "A",
  rnpr = "Variable";
$(`#rp_color_${artnr}_${rnpr}, #rp_volume_${artnr}_${rnpr}`).css('color', '#f90');
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

div[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rp_color_A_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_volume_A_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_color_B_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_volume_B_Variable"></div>
```

In this specific case, however, you may be able to use CSS attribute-selectors:

```
// here we select all <div> elements with an id attribute,
// with the value starting with the string 'rp_' and
// ending with the string contained within the 'rnpr'
// variable:
$(`div[id^=rp_][id$=${rnpr}]`)
```

```js
const artnr = "A",
  rnpr = "Variable";
$(`div[id^=rp_][id$=${rnpr}]`).css('color', '#f90');
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

div[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rp_color_A_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_volume_A_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_color_B_DifferentString"></div>
<div id="rp_volume_B_DifferentString"></div>
```

You could, of course, have the JavaScript do this for you:

```
      // here we use destructuring to assign the strings
      // to the variables:
const [artnr, rnpr] = ["A", "Variable"],

      // here we create an Array of Strings that
      // represent the start of the ID strings:
      IDPrefixes = ['#rp_color','#rp_volume'],

      // here we iterate over the Array of IDPrefixes
      // with Array.prototype.map() to create a new
      // Array:
      selectors = IDPrefixes.map(
                    // we pass the current array-value of the
                    // Array over which we're iterating into
                    // anonymous function:
                    (str) => {
                        // and we return the string formed by
                        // joining together the Array-elements
                        // of the Array we create with the
                        // variables, using the String we pass
                        // Array.prototype.join():
                        return [str, artnr, rnpr].join('_');
                  });

// here we use Array.prototype.join() again to join together the
// Array-elements of the selectors Array using a comma, which
// creates a comma-separated string of the CSS selectors we
// created earlier:
$(selectors.join(',')).css('color','#f90');
```

```js
const [artnr, rnpr] = ["A", "Variable"],
IDPrefixes = ['#rp_color', '#rp_volume'];

let selectors = IDPrefixes.map(
  (str) => {
    return [str, artnr, rnpr].join('_');
  });

$(selectors.join(',')).css('color', '#f90');
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

div[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rp_color_A_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_volume_A_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_color_B_Variable"></div>
<div id="rp_volume_B_Variable"></div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
  - [Template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive answer. Not only did you answer my question, but you took it a step further with different solutions which taught me some nice things about the basics!

Comment: You’re very welcome, I’m glad to have been of help; best of luck with your future endeavours!

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple elements, you just need: `$('selector1, selector2')`.  [**Source: api.jQuery.com: Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”).**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

But in your case, I think your quote marks are off.  `$('"#rp...` That should be just ' or ", but not both.  And there are other problems, too.  I think you're getting mixed up how variables and selectors work together.

**Explanation:** `$(...)` always expects `...` to be some a string of text.  So, you don't want to separate the variables like `$("var1selector", "var2selector")` as I see you're doing.  You want to keep it as a single string, like `$("var1selector, var2selector")`.  So, in your case...

```
$('#rp_color_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr',#rp_volume_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr).change(function() {}) 

$('#rp_color_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr',#rp_volume_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr).change(function() {}) 

$('#rp_color_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr',#rp_volume_' + artnr + '_' + rpnr).change(function() {})
```

Notice how the coloring changes when it is correctly set up?  Neat!

Comment: Using ' and " was one of my desperate attempts to get this to work :-) You noticed correctly that i did not realize the entire $(...) should be 1 string, thanks for pointing that out. Indeed, now it colors nice and clear and everything works, thank you!